# Stop safari from sharing canonical url

Tags: html, safari, mobile-safari

I recently noticed that the safari share sheet sends the canonical url when a user uses it to share a webpage.

Is there a way to overwrite that behaviour via html or some other way?

It really screws a lot of things up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is simply removing the canonical link with a timer after the document is ready with the following simple code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector("link[rel='canonical']").remove(); 
},500);
```

Comment: This is dangerous. Typically you'll have canonical for crawlers like Google, so I'm assuming if there is one, it's intentional. By removing it from the DOM, Google may not see it anymore since Google sees your pages just like Chrome does. If you change the DOM and remove stuff from it, that's what will probably get indexed. Even if this works today, I wouldn't assume it would keep doing what you'd want.

Comment: @jon_wu you are probably right, which is the main reason I added a timer, since most crawlers don't like running javascript. Also if this stops working, I'll have to remove the canonical link altogether, which is definitely a worse solution. In my use case, I have setup different domains to track different referrals, so "dangerous" is definitely not a word I would use for removing it. Still, it would hurt the SEO... probably?

Comment: 500 ms isn't much, so it's likely that Google would just see the page without the canonical link. I say dangerous under the assumption that you're using canonical for SEO reasons, and for many sites SEO is very important, but your use case may be different. Removing this can lead to duplicate content detection by Google, which could hurt your rankings. Google and Bing use Chrome to crawl now, so although JavaScript didn't used to be run by search engines that is no longer the case.

Comment: Check out this answer from Google where somebody is also using `.remove()` https://youtu.be/UH35k9y6RAY?t=2025. In their JavaScript office hours they say "if you remove it from the DOM, then we are not seeing the content." Skip to 35:15-30 for the direct answer.

Comment: So far google is not detecting duplicate content and is in fact telling me it is excluding the other urls. Also I've been using it for well over 6 months so far. I understand what you are saying, but functionality is more of a concern than SEO. It would be better if there is a less "hacky" way of getting through this, but for now, I have not figured anything out. Feel free to suggest something. I'm not emotionally attached to my answer. It was the only way though in 2 months of searching for a solution

Comment: Totally agree I'm looking for a better way too. On an e-commerce site, Google recommends using canonical for color variants of a product. It would be weird if you're looking at size 5 pink shoes, then you shared a page and asked your friend to buy them for you and you received size 12 blue shoes instead. Seems like a weird decision on Apple's part, but I think this might have been to combat AMP sharing issues.

Comment: TBH what seems to be beyond weird to me, is the lack of a meta tag to disable this option; the way they have handled pretty much all other weird "kinks" they come up with...

Comment: has there been a different solution to this question? It seems this is a still ongoing issue and it is messing up our shared links on our site... We are unable to use the solution above as it will also remove it for google...

Comment: Sadly nothing. The only thing you can do to improve this is to make some checks in javascript instead of (or in addition to) the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Since i'm using SSR and separated content from simple client and bots with node server running (that observing the agents) removing canonical does not effect your SEO so i used the answer and it was okey

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector("link[rel='canonical']").remove(); 
},500);
```

literally canonicals without SSR  are useless in angular specially when you have dynamic links like products it only gets the index.html canonical. remember that, its a negative score to change the canonical when the client get the page you must have changed it before delivering the page to bots or client.